# Creating a related or similar posts using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I was looking around SO and was wondering how would I go about in creating a related or similar posts to display on my web site using PHP & MySQL? What is a basic example of how to do this?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What kind of data do you have and how do you define a "similar post"?

Comment: @casablanca I have tags, categories and posts with titles and body content if that is what you are taking about?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using the MySQL Full Text search [`MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) thing.

Let's say your table is `articles` and you need to find related posts about a title of current post. Do it like this:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title, body) AGAINST('$CurrentPostTitle') AS score
FROM articles 
WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST('$CurrentPostTitle') 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5
```

This will give you top 5 related posts.

But first remember to enabled Full Text search for that table's columns, by running this query:

```
ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT (title, body);
```

**[EDIT]: Why to not use *`LIKE`*:** Clarification to OP:

Because it will not give correct results. Let's say you current title is "Music of 1980" and you want related posts on that. Now, if you use `LIKE` then only the posts containing EXACTLY the sequence of words "Music of 1980" will appear. However, if you use `MATCH ... AGAINST`, then posts that contain Music OR 1980 will appear. Also, the posts that contain both Music and 1980 will appear on Top because it gives a `SCORE` to each results and we are sorting by that score.I hope that's clear.

**[EDIT]: 2**:

If you have categories, you can add `AND Category = '$CurrentCategory'` in the SQL query `where clause` to get more specific results.

**[EDIT]: 3: OP can't use Full text**:

If you can not use Full Text (for some reason), you can just show 5 random posts from the same category. As they are in same category, they are somehow related at least:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles 
WHERE Category = '$CurrentCategory'
LIMIT 5
```

Edited Syntax: Changed LIMTI to LIMIT in MySQL Code

Comment: Can I use LIKE instead of FULLTEXT?

Comment: But what if I can't use FULLTEXT search sorry for all the question.

Comment: Is this thing slow? Let's say if I have 1000 articles is it OK to update *related posts* for ALL articles each time I add an article? Of course the answer depends on many things (like: how often do I add an article, what is the size of an articles, which load is critical for me and what is *slow* after all!). But generally: is this approach fast or slow?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you will want to give different weights for matching columns. You can do this on this way:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    ROUND(0 + 
               (MATCH(title) AGAINST('$CurrentPostTitle') * TITLE_WEIGHT) +
               (MATCH(body) AGAINST('$CurrentPostTitle') * BODY_WEIGHT)) AS score
FROM 
    articles 
HAVING 
    score > 0 
ORDER BY 
    score DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Just replace TITLE_WEIGHT and BODY_WEIGHT by the weight as integer.

Working this way, you will need to add FULLTEXT to each column:

```
ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT (title);
ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT (body);
```

If is the case, don't forget to exclude the current post from results. You can do this with a WHERE condition before HAVING like this:

```
WHERE id <> $CurrentPostId
```