# match() against() doesn't work but like '%$s%' does

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, sql-like

I have a fulltext field in my table. One of the rows is:

```
"this is the dog that ran over there"
```

I have the following mysql statements:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE MATCH (column) AGAINST ('dog that ran')
```

...returns 0 records

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE `column` LIKE '%dog that ran%'
```

...returns 1 record

Why the difference? They should both return 1 record, right?

Comment: This is probably due to the 50% rule - hang on, I'll look for a duplicate....

Comment: @Pekka: Could also be the minimum word like by default is four (4) characters: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129152/mysql-fulltext-search-always-has-0-results/4129223#4129223):

Fulltext search has some bizarre quirks.

For example, the behaviour described in the last paragraphs of [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) could be the reason for your problem:

> .... for example, although the word “MySQL” is present in every row of the articles table shown earlier, a search for the word produces no results:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM articles
>     -> WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('MySQL');
>  Empty set (0.00 sec)
> ```
>
> The search result is empty because the word “MySQL” is present in at least 50% of the rows. As such, it is effectively treated as a stopword. For large data sets, this is the most desirable behavior: A natural language query should not return every second row from a 1GB table. For small data sets, it may be less desirable.

The answer here would be to add more rows, or use boolean search.

Comment: that's really kind of messed up...I guess I'll use the LIKE %% search

Comment: @user yeah, but it shouldn't be that much of a problem in a live database usually. Also check out @OMG's comment above