# SQL SERVER 2005 - find related article using PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

i have a similar question with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593413/creating-a-related-or-similar-posts-using-php-mysql):. But using SQL server not Mysql. Im now using PHP and SQL SERVER 2005.

My question is: **How to find related post using PHP and SQL server?**

sorry no code, i even cant start writing code because i still dont have idea how to do this. maybe start something like this

```
<?php
$title = "Stackoverflow is one of the best website in the word";
$exp = explode(' ', $title);
$where = '';
foreach($exp as $word){
    $where .= "title LIKE '%$word%' OR body LIKE '%$word%' ";
}
$query =  "SELECT TOP 5 title FROM tbl_article WHERE $where";
?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Keep going. It looks like you might be on the right track.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks sir, but this looks ugly. i trying to search everywhere but still cant get it. There are so many similar topic but with mysql not sql server. that script can work, but i didnt know about the score. can you tell me how to get the score the closest article?