# Display Related Items PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that displays the display of an item with a specific id and I want to display other items that are related based on title, subject, or author. I am having issues with displaying related items.  Where I put my query together and execute it, the related results are just the same title of the item whose page I am already on (https://brawlins.com/soarOpen/itemRecord.php?id=65437). How do I displays related results that are not the same as the item whose page I currently am on?

```
<?php 
include("config.php");

if(!isset($_GET["id"])) {
    echo "No id passed into the page";
    exit();
}
$id = $_GET['id'];

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php
$item_query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM oer_search WHERE id = :id");
$item_query->bindParam(":id", $id);
$item_query->execute();

while($row = $item_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  

    $type = $row['type'];
    $link = $row['link'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    $pub_date = $row["publication_date"];
    $source = $row['source'];
    $isbn = $row["isbn_number"];
    $e_isbn = $row["e_isbn_number"];
    $license = $row['license'];
    $license_url = $row['license_url'];
    $base_url = $row['base_url'];
    $author = $row['author'];
    $review = $row['review'];
    $image = $row["image_url"];
    $loc_collection = $row["loc_collection"];
    $publisher = $row['publisher'];
    $pub_url = $row['publisher_url'];


?>   
<title><?php echo $title ?></title> 
<div class="container content-container">
<div class="card card-content">
<div class="card-body">


<?php

echo "<strong><a class='itemRecordLink' rel='external' href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a></strong><br/>";

}  
$like_query = $conn->prepare("SELECT title FROM oer_search WHERE title LIKE :title OR subject=:subject OR author=:author LIMIT 4");
$titleLike = $searchTerm = "%". $title . "%";
$like_query->bindParam(":title", $titleLike);
$like_query->bindParam(":subject", $subject);
$like_query->bindParam(":author", $author);
$like_query->execute();
echo "<div class='row'>";
while($row = $like_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    echo "<div class='col-md-3 text-center'>";
    if($image != "") {
            echo "<img src='$image' class='img-fluid img-thumbnail itemRecordImage' alt='cover image' /><br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<img src='images/cover-image.png' class='img-fluid itemRecordImage' alt='cover image' /><br>";
        }
    echo "<span>$title</span>";
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>

</div><!--end of card body-->
</div><!--end of card-->
</div><!--end of container-->  

<?php include 'footer.php'?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using `$image` and `$title` that weren't reassigned since the first `while`.

Comment: Another problem you'll run into - in your second query for similar items, you're only selecting the title and not the image.

Comment: Duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/3593438/12232340 you need to use match to show related (similar) posts.

Comment: Thanks @El_Vanja! That fixed it. Once I reassigned $title and $image in the second query it worked.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Aren’t they just random posts instead of similar posts ? Which is showing up now.